# HP Systems Management Homepage not working after upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant

I upgraded my HP Proliant DL380 G4 Systems Management Homepage to 6.3.0 recently & it no longer works.  OS is Windows Storage Server 2003.  I have tried uninstalling it from Add/Remove programs & re-installing, but still no joy.  In the system logs, I see:

> The HP System Management Homepage
>   Win32 service could not be stopped
>   successfully. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

It'd be nice to know which file it can't find, so I'm grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to HP support, it turns out the latest release had a bug (at least on this platform) so I had to downgrade to 6.2.x, and now it's working fine.  Just posting the answer for others to see in case they run into the same problem.

Comment: Good to know. Sometimes, it's just not your fault.

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall from the entire ProLiant Support Pack available [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&prodNameId=3884083&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-c4a548846c6241a68d6744ff70). If you upgraded a single component individually, there may have been other dependencies.

Comment: What's the difference between the Proliant Support Pack you linked to & the "Proliant Storage Server Release" pack that I see when I go to my specific server's drivers & software page?  I don't see the one you linked to on that page, which makes me wonder if it's compatible.

Comment: Well, it's still Windows 2003, but I could be wrong on the package. Is there a version 8.70 PSP for the Windows Storage Server?

Comment: Here's the downloads & software page for this specific server:  http://bit.ly/l045Qq.  I'm not seeing it there.

Comment: Based on that, you can probably download and install the ProLiant Support Pack I initially linked to. If not, download the software listed under Software - System Management: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1143915&prodTypeId=12169&prodSeriesId=1143914&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1114#7832

Comment: I'm going to try re-installing all the individual packages.  Only thing is, I wonder if they're required in a specific order?

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled everything, but it still doesn't work.  Still get the same error in the system logs.  I've restarted any relevant HP services, but still no help.  Only thing I haven't done is reboot.  The only other possibly relevant info is I upgraded IE to IE8 recently, but I can't remember if I had the problem before or after the upgrade.